# How to get the text from the HTML using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup

I want to know how I can get the text `A1 Pawn` from this HTML:

```
<tr id="overview-summary-current">
<th scope="row">
    <span class="edit-tools">
        <a href="#background-experience" class="edit-section" id="control_gen_4">Edit experience</a>
        <script id="controlinit-dust-server-65573249-4" type="text/javascript+initialized" class="li-control">LI.Controls.addControl("control-dust-server-65573249-4","IntraScroller",{tracking:'top-card-edit-experience',paddingTop:-20})</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">if(dust&&dust.jsControl){if(!dust.jsControl.flushControlIds){dust.jsControl.flushControlIds="";}else{dust.jsControl.flushControlIds+=",";}dust.jsControl.flushControlIds+="control-dust-server-65573249-4";}</script>
    </span>
    <a href="#background-experience" data-trk="prof-0-ovw-curr_pos">Current</a>
</th>
<td>
    <ol>
        <li>
            <span data-tracking="mcp_profile_sum" class="new-miniprofile-container /biz/miniprofile/8241336?pathWildcard=8241336" data-li-url="/biz/miniprofile/8241336?pathWildcard=8241336" data-li-getjs="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=40vfeoewuurexnhvi1o2qiknu&amp;fc=2" data-li-miniprofile-id="LI-2326069">
                <strong>
                    <a href="/company/8241336?trk=prof-0-ovw-curr_pos" dir="auto">A1 Pawn</a>
                </strong>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ol>
</td>
```

I've tried using CSS Selector and xpath to get the text

Using CSS selector its not working:

```
str(profilePageSource.find_element_by_css_selector("#overview-summary-current > td > ol > li > span > strong > a").get_text().encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]
```

Using Xpath its not working:

```
str(profilePageSource.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id=\"overview-summary-current\"]/td/ol/li/span/strong/a").get_text().encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`soup.find(id='overview-summary-current').td.a.text` should give you the result.

Comment: great simple but logical

Answer (score 2):

For CSS Selectors, you should use [`soup.select()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) method, not `.find_element_by_css_selector` . Example -

```
elems = profilePageSource.select("#overview-summary-current > td > ol > li > span > strong > a")
if elems:
    print(str(elems[0].get_text().encode("utf-8"))[2:-1]))
```

Demo -

```
>>> s = """<tr id="overview-summary-current">
... <th scope="row">
...     <span class="edit-tools">
...         <a href="#background-experience" class="edit-section" id="control_gen_4">Edit experience</a>
...         <script id="controlinit-dust-server-65573249-4" type="text/javascript+initialized" class="li-control">LI.Controls.addControl("control-dust-server-65573249-4","IntraScroller",{tracking:'top-card-edit-experience',paddingTop:-20})</script>
...         <script type="text/javascript">if(dust&&dust.jsControl){if(!dust.jsControl.flushControlIds){dust.jsControl.flushControlIds="";}else{dust.jsControl.flushControlIds+=",";}dust.jsControl.flushControlIds+="control-dust-server-65573249-4";}</script>
...     </span>
...     <a href="#background-experience" data-trk="prof-0-ovw-curr_pos">Current</a>
... </th>
... <td>
...     <ol>
...         <li>
...             <span data-tracking="mcp_profile_sum" class="new-miniprofile-container /biz/miniprofile/8241336?pathWildcard=8241336" data-li-url="/biz/miniprofile/8241336?pathWildcard=8241336" data-li-getjs="https://static.licdn.com/scds/concat/common/js?h=40vfeoewuurexnhvi1o2qiknu&amp;fc=2" data-li-miniprofile-id="LI-2326069">
...                 <strong>
...                     <a href="/company/8241336?trk=prof-0-ovw-curr_pos" dir="auto">A1 Pawn</a>
...                 </strong>
...             </span>
...         </li>
...     </ol>
... </td>"""
>>>
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s,'html.parser')
>>> soup.select("#overview-summary-current > td > ol > li > span > strong > a")
[<a dir="auto" href="/company/8241336?trk=prof-0-ovw-curr_pos">A1 Pawn</a>]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also get the resut by the following

```
soup.find('a', {'dir': "auto"}).text
```